# Is there an API for facebook or facebook page to report spam profiles/pages

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

I have been looking for an to report spam users/profiles/pages for facebook similar to the twitter API users/report_spam.

Let me know if anyone has some idea on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, currently there is no API to do that. You can only use the mobile/web interface for that.